Accessing Headers and Footers with python-docx
Is it possible to change a word in a word files Header and Footer using python-docx. Like i would place a {{PLACEHOLDER_TEXT}} and change it to an actual word.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources.

You can use python-docx to access and update the headers and footers of a Word file by working with the sections property. The basic steps involve accessing the header and footer of each section, then iterating through their paragraphs and, if tables exist, tables as well, and either reading or updating their content. Once you have finished your edits, you can save the document under a new name.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations, documentation, and/or example code, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
